# Using telescoping series to express a partial binomial series

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am analying 
$$
\sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}{\frac{-3}{2}\choose n-j}}{j(j-1)}\;\;\mbox{where}\;n\ge k\;\mbox{are integers}.
$$
By the telescoping series, we have
$$
\sum_{j=k}^{n}(-1)^{j}{\frac{-3}{2}\choose n-j}\left(\frac{1}{j-1}-\frac{1}{j}\right).
$$

Does it have a closed form? Maybe I should ask that if it is possible to find a closed form for

$$
\sum_{j=k}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{j}{\frac{-3}{2}\choose n-j}}{j}.
$$

Please give me some help. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that you could face some hypergeometric function (which is still worse)

Comment: Thanks. So, it does not seem to have a closed form.